# How to add different toast messages for each imageView which displayed using GridView in android

Tags: java, android, gridview

activity_main

```
<GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="8"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
  package com.example.android.whattheemoticon;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.smileys, R.drawable.animals,
                R.drawable.food, R.drawable.activities,
                R.drawable.symbols, R.drawable.objects,
                R.drawable.travel, R.drawable.flags,
        };
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.android.whattheemoticon;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //display images using gridview.
            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    //onClickListeners for each clickable imageViews.
     gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        int position, long id) {
//create toast for view when clicked.
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to add toast message for each images which are displayed using `GridView` , i'm ended up adding the code for toast to work for each grid . And i have completed adding and displaying the images in `GridView`. Please help me out for how to display the right toast message for each image while clicked by an user.

Comment: You can put the messages into an array in order according to the index of image in GridView. For example `{"Message for image 0", "Message for image 1",...}`. Then in the method `onItemClick` , declare a string variable like `String message = arrayList.get(position)` . Finally, just show them by `Toast.makeText()`

Comment: Thanks for telling. Is there any chance , if you could explain in a code . Cause I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rajashekar. Here is an example.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //display images using gridview.
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        final ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
        message.add("Message for image 0");
        message.add("Message for image 1");
        message.add("Message for image 2");
        //onClickListeners for each clickable imageViews.
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
   //create toast for view when clicked.
    String mess = message.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + mess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array like this :

```
String arr[ImageCount] = {"Message for first image", "Message for second image"......};
```

Then use a function to print Toast Message like this :

```
public void showToast(int pos){
       for(int i = 0; i<=pos; i++){
                if(i == pos){
                     Toast.makeText(Context, arr[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     break;
                 }
        }
  }
```

Now call the function :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
           showToast(position);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure. Please don't forget to vote for this answer.